# Save key_name value GAE and WTforms

Tags: google-app-engine, wtforms

I'm using WTforms with GAE and trying to figure out the best way to set the key_name value.  This works, but it is not very clean. Specifically, the p = Posts(key_name...   line seems redundant.

```
class CreatePost(BaseHandler):
def post(self):
    form = MyForm(self.request.POST)
    if form.validate():
        p = Posts()
        p.author = users.get_current_user()
        p.title = form.title.data
        p.path = format_post_path(p)
        p.content = form.content.data
        p = Posts(key_name=p.path, author=p.author, 
                       title=p.title, content=p.content, path=p.path)
        p.put()
        return webapp2.redirect('/admin/')
    else: 
        self.render_template('create.html', {'form':form})
```

I've tried to do this, but it doesn't work.

```
class CreatePost(BaseHandler):
def post(self):
    form = MyForm(self.request.POST)
    if form.validate():
        p = Posts()
        p.author = users.get_current_user()
        p.title = form.title.data
        p.path = format_post_path(p)
        p.content = form.content.data
        p.key_name = p.path
        p.put()
        return webapp2.redirect('/admin/')
    else: 
        self.render_template('create.html', {'form':form})
```

My questions:  What is the best way to write this?  why won't p.key_name = p.path work?

**UPDATE 1**

Here is the relevant code:

```
from models import Posts
import fix_path
import wtforms
from wtforms.ext.appengine.db import model_form
from wtforms import Form, TextField, validators

MyForm = model_form(Posts, Form, field_args = {
    'title' : {
        'validators' : [validators.Length(min=1, max=25)]
    },
    'content' : {
        'validators' : [validators.Length(min=4, max=100000)]
    }
})

def slugify(s):
    s = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s).encode('ascii', 'ignore').lower()
    return re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+', '-', s).strip('-')


def format_post_path(p):
    slug = slugify(p.title)
    return config.post_path_format % {
        'slug': slug,
        'year': p.date_create.year,
        'month': p.date_create.month,
        'day': p.date_create.day,
   }

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def jinja2(self):
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

    def render_template(
        self,
        filename,
        template_values,
        **template_args
        ):
        template = fix_path.jinja_environment.get_template(filename)
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))  

class CreatePost(BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
        form = MyForm(self.request.POST)
        if form.validate():
            p = Posts()
            p.author = users.get_current_user()
            p.title = form.title.data
            p.path = format_post_path(p)
            p.key_name = p.path #this part doesn't work. 
                                #No error. Just not value
                                #passed to datastore.
            p.content = form.content.data
            p.put()
            return webapp2.redirect('/admin/')
        else: 
            self.render_template('create.html', {'form':form})

    def get(self):  

        MyForm = model_form(Posts, Form)
        self.render_template('create.html', {'form':MyForm()})
```

From config file

```
post_path_format = '/%(year)d/%(month)02d/%(slug)s'
```

I just don't understand why I can use the p.key_name = p.path format (like the first snippet).  Why do I have to do p = Posts(key_name=path, author=p.author.....  (like the second snippet)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is the error your are getting? how does your model look like?

Comment: another thing. i would call the model `Post` not `Posts`. what does format_post_path(path) do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're creating a temporary Posts entity, then using it's "path" to create yet another Posts entity, which you actually save.  That's messed up in so many ways.

```
class CreatePost(BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
        form = MyForm(self.request.POST)
        if form.validate():
            p = Posts(key_name=???, users.get_current_user(), title=p.title, content=form.content.data, path=???)
            p.put()
            return webapp2.redirect('/admin/')
        else: 
            self.render_template('create.html', {'form':form})
```

This leaves the question, what's "path"?  You need to generate "path" without using an existing entity.

Also, if "path" is the entity ancestor path, I don't think that's what you actually want for your key name.

Comment: the issue is that in the second snippet he uses a function to format the path `format_post_path(p)` passing in `p` whith is `Posts()` with the set properties `title` and `author` and we dont know what this function actually does. it might use illegal chars for key_name but it could also fail in the function. but i agree this code is pretty much messed up.

Comment: I've added the code for the format_post_path(p) function.  I know that function works because the first snippet submit the path and key to the datastore just fine.  My question is why doesn't the second one work?  Why can't I simply just do p.key_name = p.path?

Comment: @Busilinks: as long as you don't provide the traceback it will be pretty hard to guess what the issue actually is.

Comment: key_name has to be passed in as a parameter to the constructor.  The code in this answer should work fine if you replace ??? with format_post_path({title:p.title,... })

Comment: My question really had more to do with syntax.  I'm getting a correctly formulated key_name value from my function.  My first example post the value to the datastore just fine. What I don't understand is why the second block of code does not work.  Having said all that, @dragonx now has me questioning if I should be using my url path as a key_name in the first place.  Again, thanks for your help and feedback.

Comment: @aschmid00 I didn't provide a traceback because I don't get an error.  In my second block of code (before the update) the problem is just that the value doesn't get saved to the datastore.  The first block works.

Comment: @Busilinks did you try to log what p.key_name and p.path is after calling `put()`? i have no problem adding a key name on a simple model in the interactive console. can you also add your complete models.py?

Comment: I did finally realize it was a syntax issue in my last comment, but I'm not sure you understood it. key_name is a constructor parameter, not an attribute.  You must pass it into the constructor, you can't set the attribute.